# Splitting a column with multiple and unevenly distributed delimiters in R

Tags: r, string, split, csv

I have a column/vector of character data that I need to separate into different columns. The problem? There are different delimiters (which mean different things), and different lengths between each delimiter. For example:

```
column_name   
akjhaa 1-29 y 12-30  
bsd, 14-20  
asdf asdf del 2-5 y 6  
dkljwv 3-31  
joikb 6-22  
sqwzsxcryvyde jd de 1-2  
pk, ehde 1-2  
jsd 1-15  
asdasd asedd 1,3
```

The numbers need to be separated into columns apart from the characters.  However, the numbers can be separated by a comma or dash or 'y'. Moreover, the numbers separated by dash should be somehow designated, as eventually, I need to make a document/vector where each of the numbers in that range is in their own column also (such that the split aaa column would become aaa 1 2 3 4 5 .... 29 12 13 ... 30).

So far, I have tried separating into columns based on the different delimiters, but because sometimes the values have more than one '-','y', or the 'y' falls as a word in one of the first character parts, it is starting to get a bit complicated...is there an easier way?

For clarification, in the particular "column_name" I gave, the final output would be such that i would have n columns, where n = (the highest number of numbers + 1 (the character string of the column name)). So, in the example of the provided "column_name," it would look like:

```
column_name n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 n8 n9 n10 n11 n12 n13 n14 n15 n16 n17 n18 n19 n20 n21 n22 n23 n24 n25 n26 n27 n28 n29 n30 n31 n32 n33 n34 n35 n36 n37 n38 n39 n40 n41 n42 n43 n44 n45 n46 n47 n48 n49 n50 n51 n52 n53 n54 n55 n56 n57 n58 
akjhaa 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  
bsd 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  
asdf asdf del 2 3 4 5 6  
dkljwv 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  
joikb 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22  
sqwzsxcryvyde jd de 1 2  
pk ehde 1 2  
jsd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  
asdasd asedd 1 3
```

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled what the desired output is. Can we get an example of the entire input's desired output?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I edited  the post to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty, but it works. The result is a `list` column with the relevant values.

```
library(magrittr)
library(splitstackshape)

setDT(mydf)[, CN := gsub("(.*?) ([0-9].*)", "\\1SPLIT\\2", column_name)] %>%
  cSplit("CN", "SPLIT") %>%
  cSplit("CN_2", "[y,]", "long", fixed = FALSE) %>%
  cSplit("CN_2", "-") %>%
  .[, list(values = list(if (is.na(CN_2_2)) CN_2_1 else CN_2_1:CN_2_2)),
    .(CN_1, rowid(CN_1))] %>%
  .[, list(values = list(unlist(values))), .(CN_1)]
#                   CN_1                values
# 1:              akjhaa       1,2,3,4,5,6,...
# 2:                bsd, 14,15,16,17,18,19,...
# 3:       asdf asdf del             2,3,4,5,6
# 4:              dkljwv       3,4,5,6,7,8,...
# 5:               joikb  6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,...
# 6: sqwzsxcryvyde jd de                   1,2
# 7:            pk, ehde                   1,2
# 8:                 jsd       1,2,3,4,5,6,...
# 9:        asdasd asedd                   1,3
```

To get the extra columns instead of a list, you would need one more line: `cbind(., .[, data.table::transpose(values)])`:

```
as.data.table(mydf)[, CN := gsub("(.*?) ([0-9].*)", "\\1SPLIT\\2", column_name)] %>%
  cSplit("CN", "SPLIT") %>%
  cSplit("CN_2", "[y,]", "long", fixed = FALSE) %>%
  cSplit("CN_2", "-") %>%
  .[, list(values = list(if (is.na(CN_2_2)) CN_2_1 else CN_2_1:CN_2_2)),
    .(CN_1, rowid(CN_1))] %>%
  .[, list(values = list(unlist(values))), .(CN_1)] %>%
  cbind(., .[, data.table::transpose(values)])
```

---

The basic idea is to do the following steps:

1. Split the column names from the values.
2. Split values separated by "y" or by a "," into new rows.
3. Split values separated by "-" into multiple columns.
4. Create your list of vectors according to the rule that if any values in the second split column are `NA`, return just the value from the first column, otherwise, create the sequence from the value in the first column to the value in the second column. Since you have duplicated "id" values because you've converted the data into a longer form, use `rowid()` to help with the grouping.
5. Consolidate the values in the list column according to the actual IDs.
6. (Optionally, in my opinion) transform the list data into multiple columns.